# Background task and writing to isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-agents

I'm struggeling with writing to the isolated storage in my background task. The reason for this is that in every run of the background task I'm downloadng data and I need to compare this data the next time the background task runs. If the data has changed then a toast notification is shown.

Problem is that the data I'm writing to the isolated storage is not saved. I can use it in the rest of the OnInvoke function but the next time the background task runs the value is gone.

Am I missing something here, I thought this was going to be easy?

EDIT:
Reading values works just fine and writing values from my main app also works just fine
The code I'm using in my OnInvoke function is this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings["WebValue"] = gtResult[i];
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to try to save to and load from isolated storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe `settings.Save();` should do it?

Comment: Yes! Never thought of it since I neved have had to use it before. Thank you! This forum is amazing!